# generic list add method

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I tried to make method which  inserts element at the specified position in this list.
Then Shifts the element & subsequent elements currently at that position to the
Right by adding one to their indices, i know there is shortcut for this method but I am suppose to do it, here what i tried to do but it's not working.

```
private T a[];
private int count;
private  int size = 0; 

public int size() { return size; }

public   void add(int index,T t) throws Exception {

    if (index < 0 || index > = a.length){   
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();  
    }

    Object[] temp = new Object[a.length + 1];  

    for (int k = 0, j = 0; j < temp.length; ++ k, ++ j){  
        if ( k == index ) {  
            temp[index] = t;  
            --k; 
        } else {
            temp[j] = a[index]; // 
        }
    }
    a = (T[]) temp;
}
```

Comment: The trick to shifting is to start from the *right*, like `for (int i = last; i >= first; i--){ temp[i+1]=temp[i];}`

Comment: The result of calling `add()` is usually that the list ends up *larger*, so the fact that `size` remains unchanged is a huge warning sign!! --- Related to that, should the check be `index > size` instead of `index >= a.length`?

Answer (score 1):

The trick to shifting is to start from the right, so:

```
for (int i = size; i > index; i--) {
    a[i] = a[i - 1];
}
```

btw, when increasing size, normallyyou would *double* its size,rather than just growing by 1.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected your 'for' block, try this:

```
for (int k = 0, j = 0; j < temp.length; ++k, ++j){  
    if ( k == index ) {  
        temp[index] = t;  
        --k;
        index = -1;
    } else {
        temp[j] = a[k]; 
    }
}
```

2 fixes i added:

- `index = -1;` - In order to enter the if condition only 1 time, else it will constantly enter the condition
- `temp[j] = a[k];` - replaced to a[k], you was always taking value from a[index] means the same place, this is incorrect.

good luck :)